# Laravel 5 - Loading Relationships Triggers Server Error 500

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, relationships

I just bought a Managed VPS on GoDaddy (with CentOS6 + cPanel, Apache 2.4.10, PHP 5.5) and moved my Laravel5 app from a GoDaddy shared hosting.

The app seems to be working, but I get an Internal Server Error 500 at a particular point where I eager-load some relationships. FYI, it's definitely not a .htaccess problem, as passing an empty array in the byGuid() method eliminated the error. Also, the relationships, when called directly as $obj->relationshipName, and not being eager-loaded, seems to work fine.

Request URI:
`http://somedomain.com/object/view/76a7443f-9e49-4634-9881-b9a936eb4e4c`

Controller:

```
public function getObject(ViewObjectRequest $request) {
           $object = $this->objectsRepo->byGuid($request->guid, [
            'latestAmbientTemp',
            'latestHumidity',
            'latestWeight'
        ]);

        //some other code here, irrelevant....
   }
```

Repository:

```
public function byGuid($obj_guid, array $relationships = []){
        if(!is_null($obj= Obj::where('guid', $obj_guid)
            ->with($relationships)
            ->first())) return $obj;
    }
```

Relationships in Object:

```
public function latestAmbientTemp() {
        return $this->hasOne('BST\Models\TemperatureAmbient')->latest();
    }

public function latestHumidity() {
        return $this->hasOne('BST\Models\Humidity')->latest();
    }

public function latestWeight() {
        return $this->hasOne('BST\Models\Weight')->latest();
    }
```

Laravel log in `storage/logs/somelog.log` is empty.
Apache log does not give any details about the errors:

```
[15/Dec/2015:07:45:14 -0700] "GET /obj/view/76a7443f-9e49-4634-9881-b9a936eb4e4c HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
```

Any ideas? I'm really stuck on this and removing the eager-loads is not desirable, so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
It gives Error 500 even if I change the byGuid() method to:

```
public function byGuid($obj_guid, array $relationships = []){
            $obj= Obj::where('guid', $obj_guid)
                ->first();
            if(!is_null(obj)) return $obj->load($relationships);
        }
```

Meaning the problem is definitely in the relationships eager-loading. Has anyone encountered such an issue before?

Comment: Perhaps you are hitting a memory limit - what resources does the VPS have? And you need to check your error log not access log

Comment: It's a 1GB server. My shared hosting was also 1GB and I didn't have any problems there. The error log (in cPanel>Error log) doesn't get any new errors once I hit the URL, nor is the associated error_log file on the server. The Apache config has error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors=On

Comment: You mention a CPanel error log - does this show the items from the Apache error log? On my servers, 500 errors caused by PHP show up there.

Comment: It was a memory_limit issue. My server's value was 32MB and was too low for the data intensive scripts that were being run. Settings the value in php.ini to -1 (i.e. no limit) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be this code:

```
public function byGuid($obj_guid, array $relationships = []){
    if(!is_null($hive = Obj::where('guid', $obj_guid)
        ->with($relationships)
        ->first())) return $obj;
}
```

I notice that you're returning `$obj`, but `$obj` is not defined in this method.

The reason you're not seeing the error when you pass an empty array is that `$hive` will be `null`, so the `return $obj;` statement is never executed.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo here, $hive should be $obj . The problem remains.